# Declaring hex number: The name 'B9780' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, hex

I don't know why it says this:

> The name 'B9780' does not exist in the current context

I have the following code:

```
class Program
{
    public static int TimerBase = 00DB9780;
}
```

I expect it to accept that, but it says:

> Cannot implicitly  convert type `double` to `int`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`00DB9780` is represented as hexadecimal.  To declare as an `int` prefix the value with `0x`:

```
public static int TimerBase = 0x00DB9780;
                          //  ^^ add 0x to start of hex numbers
```

Prefixing with `0x` tells the compiler to expect (and parse) a hexadecimal number.

---

### Explanation of error(s)

The reason the compiler is saying cannot convert int to double is the first part of the value `00D` is actually one way to declare a `double` in C#.  See [Real literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types#real-literals) for more info. So the compiler interprets your intention as:

```
public static int TimerBase = 0D;  // LHS is int, RHS is double
```

So you get the error:

> cannot implicitly convert type `double` to `int`

The compiler expects to see a `;` after the `double` declaration (`00D`) so it also shows an error for missing semi-colon:

> ; expected

Next the compiler sees `B9780` which it tries to interpret as a variable which is why you get the error:

> 'B9780' does not exist in the current context